# Primefaces - how to pass parameter between 2 ui:define

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I need to pass a parameter between two forms both being in a separate ui:define.

I have a web site where left part of it is a tree table and center part is a form. I want to click a node on the left side and pass its id to the center part which will use it later on.

The goal is to enable the user to add new categories to the left side treetable. So I came up with an idea that if the user clicks a '+' sign on the treetable a form is displayed which was hidden until then.

This is the main part of the layout.

```
        <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="600" header="Categories" resizable="true" closable="false" collapsible="true">
            <h:form>
                <ui:insert name="westContent">West default content</ui:insert>
            </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="center">
            <h:form>
                <ui:insert name="centerContent">Center default content</ui:insert>
            </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>
```

This is the left side content where treetable is. I want to pass document.id to another form located in the centerContent.

```
<ui:define name="westContent">
    <h:form id="form">

        <p:treeTable value="#{documentsController.root}" var="document"
                     selection="#{documentsController.selectedNodes}" selectionMode="single">

            <p:column style="width:300px">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Name
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{document.name}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column style="width:20px">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Add Category
                </f:facet>
                <p:commandButton value="+" styleClass="ui-priority-primary"
                                 actionListener="#{editorBean.print}"
                                 onclick="addCategory.show();">
                </p:commandButton>

            </p:column>

        </p:treeTable>

    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

This is the center content where I want the document.id to be passed into.

```
<ui:define name="centerContent">
    <h:form id="addCategoryForm">
        <p:panel id="addCategory" widgetVar="addCategory" header="New Category" style="margin-bottom:10px;" closable="true" visible="false">
            <p:messages id="messages" />
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Name: *" />
                <p:inputText id="name" value="#{editorBean.name}" required="true" label="Name">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="2" />
                </p:inputText>
                <p:message for="name" />

                <h:outputLabel for="description" value="Description: *" />
                <p:inputText id="description" value="#{editorBean.description}" required="true" label="Description"/>
                <p:message for="description" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                <h:outputLabel value="Html" />
                <pe:ckEditor id="editor" value="#{editorBean.html}" interfaceColor="#cccccc" />

                <p:commandButton id="submitButton" value="Submit" update="addCategoryForm" 
                                 icon="ui-icon-disk" actionListener="#{editorBean.print}" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

This is the structure of the managed bean I'm using.

```
@ManagedBean
@Scope("view")
public class EditorBean {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String html;
    private boolean isCategory;
    private int id;

}
```

I'm used to working with jsp and the old style of handling things in constructors so this is pretty confusing to me. I'm open to any other solutions to this issue.

I thought I can fill the id from the treetable into the EditorBean and fill the rest later on but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a property in your bean that keeps the currently selected document by a command button from the left form and have it accessed from the right form in any way you see it.

For example, add a property to your bean:

```
private Document selected;//getter + setter
```

Preset it in command button's action method (EL 2.2 and higher), or by using `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` (EL lower than 2.2). Also note that `onclick` is a wrong place to hook on AJAX callback events, use `oncomplete` instead:

```
<p:commandButton value="+" styleClass="ui-priority-primary"
                 actionListener="#{editorBean.print}"
                 action="#{editorBean.action(document)}"
                 oncomplete="addCategory.show();">
</p:commandButton>
```

with

```
public void action(Document document) {
    selected = document;
    //other business logic
}
```

or:

```
<p:commandButton value="+" styleClass="ui-priority-primary"
                 actionListener="#{editorBean.print}"
                 oncomplete="addCategory.show();">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{editorBean.selected}" value="#{document}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

This way the currently clicked item will be available in your bean. You can decompose it in an action method, if you want. It can be referenced by the other form and the other form's id could be included in AJAX update so that these changes would be reflected in it.

Comment: It's still not working. I've tried both approaches you mentioned and neither worked. I've noticed that if I replace the whole commandButton with just #{editorBean.action(document)} it actualy sets something into the editorBean.

Also I can't update another form by id unless I'm doing something wrong. Both update=":addCategoryForm" and update="addCategoryForm" didn't work for me.

Comment: Cannot find component with identifier "addCategory" referenced from "j_idt11:form:j_idt12:0:ajax".

Comment: First of all, get rid of nested HTML forms (remove form tag in master template). Next, `update=":addCategoryForm"` must work based on information presented so far.

Comment: Removing nested forms helped with the component not found error. 

But it still doesn't work. It doesn't even call the action method in editorBean.

Comment: I'm trying both approaches (with and w/o the f:setPropertyActionListener).

Comment: Cleaning the whole page actualy helped. I was testing a lot of things and the code got nasty causing unexpected exceptions.